# How to get asp.net dropdownlist to allow selections

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist on a webform that I fill from a sql query, I then want to be able to select individual items in the dropdown and have corresponding fields from a datatable fill textboxes on the form
Problem is rowSel is returning 0 and the dropdown won't let me select any other item it always snaps back to the first itenm in the list.

Thought this might have something to do with autopostback being set to true, but if I set it to false that causes otheer problems, Not sure what else to try Im a winforms person and very new to asp.net

```
    protected void ddClients_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowSel = ddClients.SelectedIndex;
        txtClient.Text = dsShow.Rows[rowSel["ClientsTableFieldA"].ToString();
    }
```

It should allow me to select a value from the drop down then populate some textboxes with fields from the datatable.

Comment: `rowSel["ClientsTableFieldA"]` ...what is this supposed to mean? `rowSel` is a simple integer in your code. Doesn't this cause an error?

Comment: ClientsTableFeildA is the name of a field in the datatable and rowSel is the row number, that part seems to work, the only problem is I can only select the first record in the dropdown.

Comment: Maybe what you've shown above isn't quite correct then because there should be a syntax error due to a missing bracket, at the very least

Comment: Thanks ADyson, missed that, I think I got it worked out, to do what I want it to do, I'm gong to have to reload it from the Database, Irritating but that's all I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 protected void ddClients_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtClient.Text = ddClients.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I got part of the problem cleared up, needed (!Page.IsPostback) in page load now it allows me to select different items, however now it wont read my datatable in SelectedIndexChanged so I can get t he other values and put them in the textboxes. Any Ideas?Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void ddClients_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtClient.Text = ddClients.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

As suggested by B. Seberle
DDL items have fields value and text so it depends how you bound the ddl to SQL datasource.

place break point on  txtClient.Text = ddClients.SelectedItem.Text see if item list is empty.

it should not be necessary but you can force a ddClient.databind() in page_load if(!Page.IsPostback).

however ddClients_SelectedIndexChanged will only trigger on postback.